# Test environment beside practical environment for nodejs applications

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pm2

Before I asked, I`ve searched a lot and there are many articles about it. But my question is a little deeper.
I have an application using **Nodejs Expressjs + MongoDB + Reddit + PM2 clustering mode + Bitcoin and card getaway + API system**.

My problem is when I'm developing this application in real mode and it`s really awful. sometimes I release little updates in codes, and I press "**pm2 log**" it shows me some error in syntax or something else and I try to fix that and release again. During this time, the application with many users is down.

Also, I have to say something such as Bitcoin payment, needs real tests. Needs request and response from Blockchain.  How can I have a test environment that I can test everything exactly same as real mode and then if everything was fine, then deploy that to real mode?

An environment that easy to code and test then easy to deploy? Can Mocha help me exactly what I need? I`m using PM2 clustering mode.

Comment: This is too broad a topic. Split this up into many smaller topics.

Comment: The main thing was about text environment exactly like real one.

Comment: @Zlatko Could you help me split it to get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a proper question, but rather a layer of questions, some opinion-based, some too broad to answer. But let's try breaking it down.

The stated problem is `when I'm developing this application in real mode.... I release updates ... it shows me syntax error... application is down`. I will read it as the main problem is that you're developing on a production environment. Let's forget for a while how lousy a practice that is, and let's focus on something constructive.

Let's define rough steps to take.

1. Live environment

The most pressing problem seems to be that you work on live app, where crashing it during dev means crashing it for your users as well. Let's deal with that.

- Immediatelly change all your access codes, keys, usernames and passwords so that you store them in an environment file (which is safe to encrypt and backup, but not commited in source code), say, `environment-prod.env`.
- Then create a second set of credentials for all the services that you use. For MongoDB, e.g. it's easy, just create a local database instance, called, say, test_database. For Reddit, create a second app, cal it my-app-test, for example. Some services might have an option to create a set of *test* credentials right there in the app, with others you'll simply have one app for test, one for production.
- Create a new environment file, e.g. `test-environment.env`, with all the same keys (e.g. REDDIT_APPID, REDDIT_SECRET, MONGODB_URL, BLOCKCHAIN_GATEWAY_KEY etc), but new values.

Now, for one, you have a test environment. Make an alias, e.g. `alias dev="cd $HOME/projects/my-reddit-bitcoin-app && source test-environment.env"`. Every day you come to work on the app, type `dev`, then you can start pm2 etc and work safely in dev environment. Your users will never see your crashes.

Only when you're sure you have a new feature or bugfix completed, switch environment (`source environment-production.env`) and then deploy the new app to the server where it runs, and pm2 restart or whatever you use for these deployments. Switch back to test env immediately before working on the code anew.

Read up more on how to separate test/prod environments. Read a bit on git workflows (e.g. branch off of latest master to a feature-branch or bugfix branch, when tested, merge it back in. Then tag it "release-" and deploy to production. Then go automate all that if possible.)

2. Testing

Mocha is perfectly suitable for running tests for a Node/Express app. It's the tests that matter.

You say `bitcoin payment....Needs request and response`. Let's see how to do that.

- Add [nock])(https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) to your app (`npm i -D nock`).
- import it and put it on top of your test file. E.g. at the top of the some-test.spec.js file:

  `const nock = require('nock')`
- start recording requests e.g. add this in your `before()` block in the app:

  `describe('My tests', function () {
    before(function () {
      nock.recorder.rec();
    });
    // ... tests`
- Now, run one test at a time (e.g. write one test that does one specific task from your app) and check what's in the console. E.g. if you make a request (request.post('http://reddit.com/api/submit', jsonData)), you'll see nock printing the exact response (in JSON format) in console, as the test runs. Copy that in the test file, e.g. put it at the bottom as:

  `var testResponse = <whatever was in the console in json format. Or string, whatever>. // homework is to find out why var and not const, if this is at the end of the file.`
- Now stop the recorder (comment it out), and in your actual test, run this instead:

  `const pipe = nock('http://www.example.com')
    .get('/resource')
    .reply(200, testResponse);`
- do that for all your requests.

Now what you have is a test setup so that when you change the code, it should not run against the real Reddit api, or real payment gateway api, but get your mocked responses instead. Pair it up with some good assertions and you should be fine. Make sure you mock everything. If you add new types of requests, make sure to record them, and add them to your procedure.

Now, all this is very vague. Broad. Just one way to do it. Lengthy process. Probably not the best one. Not tailored to your specific conditions. But it should get you started. Take those things, step by step, and if you get stuck, come back to Stackoverflow. But do start working on it, because your current method seems to be unsustainable in the long run.

Comment: Thank so much and appreciated your awesome answer. I started and done something cool now. But I did not exactly get the parts related to : "alias dev="cd $HOME/projects/my-reddit-bitcoin-app && source test-environment.env" " and "environment-prod.env" !! You mean in PM2?

Comment: Well, not really. Before you run pm2, you need to setup the env files for it to pick up.